# Sorting a csv object by dates in python

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I am trying to read and sort a csv file that has data that looks like

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume
27-Mar-12   8.25    8.35    8.17    8.19    9801989
26-Mar-12   8.16    8.25    8.12    8.24    8694416
23-Mar-12   8.05    8.12    7.95    8.09    8149170
```

I do this with

```
import csv
data = csv.reader(open('data.csv','r'))
```

To sort data by Date. I do:

```
sorteddata = sorted(data,key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=False)
```

The problem is, that it sorted the dates by reading them as String and not as dates. So the data is sorted like so,

```
['3-Aug-11', '7.06', '7.23', '6.84', '7.16', '31583617']
['3-Feb-12', '7.02', '7.12', '6.98', '7.08', '15318044']
['3-Jan-12', '5.53', '5.59', '5.44', '5.48', '12678923']
['3-Jun-11', '8.09', '8.17', '7.92', '7.97', '21273812']
['3-May-11', '9.00', '9.04', '8.63', '8.80', '17356005']
```

Does anybody know how to sort by dates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to get a `datetime` from the date field:

```
from datetime import datetime

data = sorted(data, key = lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d-%b-%y"))
```

Comment: +1. Didn't know you could sort on `datetime.datetime` objects directly - looking at the docs, they *do* implement the `<` operator. Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `time` module for time format conversions, and convert your time strings (`3-Aug-11`) into numbers you can sort.

Here's some food for thought:

```
>>> t = time.strptime("3-Aug-11","%d-%b-%y")
>>> t
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=3, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=215, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> time.mktime(t)
1312300800.0
```

[Documentation for `time` module.](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime)