# What's wrong with this code for sorting csv file according to date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sorting

I have this csv file which look like this:

```
datetime_period,value
01 Apr 2021 00:00,92.85
01 Apr 2021 00:30,91.73
11 Feb 2021 19:30,88.58
11 Feb 2021 20:00,88.58
13 Jan 2021 13:00,80.49
13 Jan 2021 13:30,81.95
```

I want to sort this csv according to the datetime in column `datetime_period`.

I used this link [Sorting a csv object by dates in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917865/sorting-a-csv-object-by-dates-in-python/) as a guide.

Here is my code;

```
data = csv.reader(open(csv_file_path, 'r'))
data = sorted(data, key=lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d %b %Y %H:%M"))
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: time data 'ï»¿time_period' does not match format '%d %b %Y %H:%M'
python-BaseException
```

I looked at the code and think my code does match the `datetime` format.
Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code or provide an alternative solution?

I am using python 3.8.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to skip the header row at the beginning of the file. This can easily be done by passing the `csv.reader` object to the built-in [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function to iterate it once. The code below shows how to do that and have the file closed properly after its contents have been read.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

csv_file_path = 'time_data.csv'

with open(csv_file_path, 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # Skip over header row.
    data = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d %b %Y %H:%M"))

print(data)
```

If you're unsure whether a header is present or not, you can do the skipping conditionally — see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11350095/355230) to the *very* similar [How to ignore the first line of data when processing CSV data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349333/how-to-ignore-the-first-line-of-data-when-processing-csv-data) question.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to sort your header line, which does not contain `datetime` values.

A way around this is to `pop` off the headers prior to sorting, and add them back after.

```
data = [line for line in csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'r'))]

headers = data.pop(0)

data = sorted(data, key=lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d %b %Y %H:%M"))
#[['13 Jan 2021 13:00', '80.49'], ['13 Jan 2021 13:30', '81.95'], ['11 Feb 2021 19:30', '88.58'], ['11 Feb 2021 20:00', '88.58'], ['01 Apr 2021 00:00', '92.85'], ['01 Apr 2021 00:30', '91.73']]

out = [headers] + data

#[['datetime_period', 'value'], ['13 Jan 2021 13:00', '80.49'], ['13 Jan 2021 13:30', '81.95'], ['11 Feb 2021 19:30', '88.58'], ['11 Feb 2021 20:00', '88.58'], ['01 Apr 2021 00:00', '92.85'], ['01 Apr 2021 00:30', '91.73']]
```